# How to search hidden directories/files with path=.,** and :find?

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

I have been using [junegunn/fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) to quickly find (hidden and non-hidden) files in vim. I [just found](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2555/19268) out that it's also possible to set

```
path=.,**
```

and use `:find some-file` to achieve pretty much the same except fuzzy-searching. Since I rarely use fuzzy-searching and prefer to use as little plugins as possible (it's still a ton though), I am thinking about abonding fzf.vim and completely switching to the path/:find-approach.

That said, there is one important feature missing for me here. As far as I can tell, `path` doesn't include hidden directories. For example, given the following directory structure

```
~/testdir
❯ tree -a
.
|-- .hidden-folder
|   |-- some-hidden-file
|   `-- some1-hidden
|       `-- some2-hidden
|           `-- deeply-hidden-file
|-- some-file
`-- some-folder
    `-- some1
        `-- some2
            `-- deep-file

6 directories, 4 files
```

and opening `vim some-file`, `:find deeply-hidden` does not find the file. I assume this is because it is inside a `.hidden-folder` since `:find deep-file` is found.

Is there some way I can set `**` to include hidden folders as well? Maybe it's also possible to tell vim to use a specific command for searching, so I can configure it to include hidden files/folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in routine used for searching files uses a "depth-first search" algorithm which makes it quite inefficient in many scenarios. `set path=.,**` may thus be a bit excessive as it will force Vim to look into every subdirectory before switching to the next directory. It *may* work in some cases (as emphasized in my answer you linked to) but you should know that `'path'` is intended as a list of specific directories and having `**` in there kind of defeats its point. The "right" way to make `:find` go through hidden directories is to add them to `'path'`:

```
set path+=.some_dir
set path+=.some_other_dir
```

While it would certainly be an improvement over the current situation, replacing the current algorithm with a "better" one (say 
[iterative deepening depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)) can only be done in Vim's C source as Vim doesn't expose a `'filesearchprg'` option or similar, unfortunately.

Comment: I see. Maybe using fzf.vim with [sharkdp/fd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678488/2300759) remains the way to go then. (Thank you for giving some more background by mentioning iterative deepening depth-first search.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably want `path=.,,**` not `path=.,**`. `.` is the directory of the edited file, the empty string (between `,,`) is the current folder - where the editor is running.

As for your question, like @romainl says in the other answer, unfortunately there isn't an option you can set that would cause `**` to recurse into hidden directories as well.

*But*, you can sort of hack your way around this by setting `path+=**/.*/**,**/.*/**/.*/**`. This should help with `:find`ing `deeply-hidden-file`, in your case. It's a "hack" because it finds `a/b/.c/d/.e/f/g` but won't find `a/.b/.c/d/.e/f` for example, because it's under 3 levels of hidden directories. So to get that to work you'd need to add `path+=**/.*/**/.*/**/.*/**`... as you will see that slows the search down a bit.

---

**NB** Only tried this in NeoVim, although it should work in Vim, too.